# MS Word: fix for old version of header displayed on some clients?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an MS Word document that was first created a long time ago (like 20 years). Over the subsequent years the document has been altered and now has the company's current branding in its header. However, when viewed with certain clients, e.g., the iPhone Outlook app, the document is displayed with a previous version of the headers with outdated company branding.

Is there some way I can view and remove this older version of the header? When I open the document in the version of Word that's on my Win 10 laptop (MS365 Enterprise v2211), I see only the current correct header.

(I'm sure that I can solve the problem in this specific instance by creating a new document and copy-pasting or something, but I'm looking for a solution that's repeatable and understandable by non-technical staff so that they can find and correct the same issue in other documents of the same vintage [before the company president stumbles on them, which is how the problem at hand was discovered].)

Comment: Some possible causes: perhaps Z-ordering has gone wrong so that an old header now shows "above" a new header. Or field codes were used with coding that displays one heading rather than another, in which case working out what the codes do might help you fix that. .doc files used to be able to store multiple versions of a document and I suppose the error could be related to that, but it seems unlikely given that you are using a modern version of Word.

Comment: Is there a way to see and manipulate the headers that aren’t z0? When I open the doc in my up to date version of Word, I see the current correct header, but I don’t know how to view the older header, which is presumably z1 or z2.

Comment: I don't have a procedure you could follow, but if what you see is an image that you do not want, what happens if you delete it?

In Word, you basically have "stuff in front of text", "text", and "stuff behind text". Unfortunately, for two images both "behind text", re-ordering via sending back or forwards doesn't seem all that useful, especially when you have similar-sized images where it is difficult to select one of the images. Currently working in Mac Word where things may be a little different.

Comment: Older word docs that have had multiple authors can prove exceptionally 'sticky' regarding formatting.  It isn't a hundred percent effective, but I'm curious to know, what happens if you apply the Clear All Formatting function in the Header/Footer field?

Comment: I tried Clear All Formatting, which just shifts the header image to the left, which is how the alignment is configured in the document for the Normal style.

Comment: This seems weird, but Word can still remember the title 20 years ago when it has been changed? Are these client versions showing old titles earlier versions of Word? Have the same problem on different devices in modern versions?

Comment: So far the only place that I've been able to see the old header is the Outlook app on an iPhone. If I open the doc on the same iPhone from OneDrive, the current header is correctly displayed. The old header has branding that would have been replaced at least 10 years ago, so there's no mistaking it. I imagine that it has something to do with change tracking, although my current version of Word on Win 10 tells me that change tracking is turned off for the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Visual Studio plugin called [OOXML Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuenm18.ooxml-viewer) I opened the doc. There are multiple headers, including one with an image called "US Logo 2009", which is my troublemaker.

Next, I renamed the .docx file as a .zip and opened it with 7-zip where I deleted the old header. Then I changed the name back to a .docx and viewed it with the iPhone Outlook app. The document is now displayed with the correct current header.

This isn't a real answer to my initial question because none of the above is replicable by non-tech staff, but I'm confident that I can at least write a little tool to comb through the corp doc library and at least identify files that have the issue.